# In CUDA programming how to understand if the GPU kernel has completed its task?

Tags: cuda

In CUDA programming suppose I am calling a kernel function from the host.

Suppose the kernel function is,

```
my_kernel_func(){
 doing some tasks utilizing multiple threads
}
```

Now from the host I am calling it using,

```
my_kernel_func<<<grid,block>>>();
```

In the NVDIA examples, they have called three more functions afterwards,

```
cudaGetLastError()
```

**CUDA Doc :** Returns the last error that has been produced by any of the runtime calls in the same host thread and resets it to **cudaSuccess.**

```
cudaMemcpy()
```

**CUDA Doc :** Copies count bytes from the memory area pointed to by **src to** the memory area pointed to by **dst,** where kind specifies the direction of the copy, and must be one of **cudaMemcpyHostToHost,** **cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,** **cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,** **cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice,** or **cudaMemcpyDefault.** Passing **cudaMemcpyDefault** is recommended, in which case the type of transfer is inferred from the pointer values. However, **cudaMemcpyDefault** is only allowed on systems that support unified virtual addressing. Calling **cudaMemcpy()** with **dst** and **src** pointers that do not match the direction of the copy results in an undefined behavior.

and then

```
cudaDeviceSynchronize()
```

**CUDA Doc :** Blocks until the device has completed all preceding requested tasks. **cudaDeviceSynchronize()** returns an error if one of the preceding tasks has failed. If the **cudaDeviceScheduleBlockingSync** flag was set for this device, the host thread will block until the device has finished its work.

Now I have tried to put a print statement at the end of the kernel function,

```
my_kernel_func(){
 doing some tasks utilizing multiple threads
 print D
}
```

As well as printed at different locations of the sequential flow,

```
cudaGetLastError()
print A
cudaMemcpy()
print B
cudaDeviceSynchronize()
print C
```

This thing prints in the following order

```
A
D
B
C
```

Basically, I need the time by which the kernel completes its task. Now I am confused to take the ending time. Because there should be a considerable time taken for copying back the data. Now if I put the ending time stamp after that it might incorporate the copying time also.

Is there any other function available to catch the ending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the documentation, [cudaMemcpy()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1gc263dbe6574220cc776b45438fc351e8) exhibits synchronous behavior, so the [cudaDeviceSynchronize()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g10e20b05a95f638a4071a655503df25d) turns into a no-op because the synchronization was done at the memcpy.

The [cudaGetLastError()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__ERROR.html#group__CUDART__ERROR_1g3529f94cb530a83a76613616782bd233) checks whether you make an okay kernel call.

If you want to time for the kernel and not the memcpy's, switch the order of the cudaMemcpy()/cudaDeviceSynchronize() calls, start the timer just before the kernel call, then get the timer value after the cudaDeviceSynchronize() call. Make sure to test the result of cudaDeviceSynchronize() call as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. Swapping the two functions actually saved the day.